# Why is the Late Answers queue so short?

Tags: discussion, late-answers

I have reviewed 250 Qs on Triage and working towards badge for First Posts.  However, it seems like there is hardly ever more than one Late Answer waiting for me, and they disappear pretty quickly.  Is it because-

- There just aren't a lot of late answers -- most questions are answered quickly and the remaining ones don't get a lot of traffic due to low visibility or quality
- Reviewing late answers is a popular review activity -- people like to do these instead of First Posts, which are often painful (but helpful towards Deputy badge)
- Some other reason

Is it ideal that this queue is often empty?  I imagine that it could be filled by relaxing the time definition of a Late Answers or by increasing the required consensus, and that would give low-status reviewers something to work on (and might help with quality).

Comment: Late-answer and first-post are single-shot queues: There is no consensus neccessary. Which is the reason not using "skip" where appropriate is extra-bad there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That the queue is often empty has to do with two things: there are few questions coming in, and they have to be reviewed by only one person to get out. The latter is just a result of the way the queue is set up.

If you look at the [stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) you can see that there have been "only" 757K reviews. The only queues with a lower amount of reviews are the Reopen queue and the recently added Help & Improvement queue. You can also often see on that page, that there are people maxing out at 20 reviews a day. These are probably reviewers that use some programmatic help to get notified of pending reviews.¹

If you select a review you have some time before it gets reallocated and you loose the chance to actually "do" the review. So if you  have a program check much more often than you would yourself manually, and get notified that there is something to do, that is much more effective in "getting" reviews, than hoping that one will pop up, or that you hit one by selecting the review page a few times an hour, when you think about it.

On the other hand the goal of the queue is not to be there for people to have things to review, as you seem to be suggesting. There is no need to have Late Answers to review, it is a side-effect. If you want something to do there are always answers to give (which is the primary goal of the site) or post to improve by editing, which both can be done with your reputation level. These would get you reputation, and can get you many more badges than the 3 for reviewing up to 1000 items on the Late Answer queue.

Once you have enough reputation you can also review the other queues, some of which seem always full, some of which are mostly empty. It is possible to get (gold) steward badges on all of them with some determination and time, as several of us [have shown](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/311167/most-steward-badges-by-number-and-date). But think about it whether this should be your main goal, or just a side effect of contributing to the site (which reviewing of course is one of the possible ways to do).

---

¹ <sub>I have no proof for that, that is my impression. And I am not suggesting that these people don't do proper reviews. Enhancing your chances to grab a review shouldn't relate to the quality of the review itself, it can easily improve it, as you would be more likely to skip instead of review anything you get your hands on.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Because we're so quick at answering.

On a more serious note, I can think of a few reasons why.  Late answers are comparatively rare, and relatively easy to moderate.

What we're looking for in the late answers queue are people doing searches on the site and depositing their spammy messages wherever they think they might have the slightest bit of relevance.

We're also looking for people posting "I have the same problem, has anyone found an answer?"

Both of those are fairly easy to spot.

Comment: First answer +1 -- but it was a mostly serious question